# How to make elements with z-index=1 , responsive in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am using the code described here in [codepen](https://codepen.io/bev/pen/vZNJWr/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=511bdcb92e65401d27c4556b2f901fd2ffb3ec70-1587932579-0-AQM1dDAU4XsHQV1d41byF2BNxcVK8MZNUO93wUsUSlzgxb2zWJ-_eoOF6KRqOWxByAYehPJm76-bccgFTPllj7VFk87EVpiOBwda06Q_SVRAhu0uAJ1kTwbeihVj6WSpbQE7N9tRes1Byd0SSOEUnEJXtDiKz0EWQvxqHJHuUf5d9Q6SR3my944D5eWXZ3elntx59iVInWI1rjZhaaVtIFGoSf9MAu1OW9sP1HjLMr_BL8jhnG_vvUepbekUbpe-ff20HmA8Rq10Kcq-PiPTOTc8En4Mga1l6MErtKFALaqOcE3A_hth4m9Pv2UgUwqBKsNnNblJ8TbqagG7VKpw15-SGsQfKzEqMpezf3HwABJS), i am using an image of USA map instead of the world map. But since the code here uses z-index=1 on dots, they aren't getting responsive.

I tried vh and vw, tried percentages, but when ever i resize my screen, the dots get all over the place.

Can anyone help on how to make these dots responsive? I just want them to stay on the map, no matter where on the map.

Note: If you have some other way of achieving the same thing, please mention.

Here's the code on codepen:
**HTML**:

```
<div id="map">
  <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/reddelicious/image/upload/v1496891721/map_no-dots_mptb8a.png" alt="Map">
  </div>
  <div id="dots">
      <div class="dot dot-1"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-2"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-3"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-4"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-5"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-6"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-7"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-8"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-9"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-10"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-11"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-12"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-13"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-14"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-15"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-16"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-17"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-18"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-19"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-20"></div>
      <div class="dot dot-21"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
/* Original pulsing dots by sharla */

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(52, 106, 180, 1);} 
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px rgba(52, 106, 180, 0.0);}
}

body {
    background-color: #111114;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#map {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dot {
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: pulse 1.5s infinite ease-out;
    background: #346ab4;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 3px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
    &:nth-child(odd) { 
        animation: pulse 1.5s infinite ease-out 0.3s; 
    }
    &-1 { top: 34%; left: 14.5%; }
    &-2 { top: 43%; left: 15.5%; }
    &-3 { top: 51%; left: 20.5%; }
    &-4 { top: 61%; left: 27%; }
    &-5 { top: 68%; left: 29%; }
    &-6 { top: 79%; left: 29%; }
    &-7 { top: 39%; left: 47%; }
    &-8 { top: 30%; left: 46%; }
    &-9 { top: 27%; left: 47%; }
    &-10 { top: 31%; left: 47.5%; }
    &-11 { top: 34%; left: 48.5%; }
    &-12 { top: 47%; left: 53%; }
    &-13 { top: 56%; left: 47.5%; }
    &-14 { top: 78%; left: 53%; }
    &-15 { top: 56%; left: 76%; }
    &-16 { top: 62%; left: 78%; }
    &-17 { top: 41%; left: 79%; }
    &-18 { top: 52%; left: 70%; }
    &-19 { top: 26%; left: 51.5%; }
    &-20 { top: 39%; left: 27%; }
    &-21 { top: 82%; left: 88.5%; }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        &:before {
            width: 4px;
            height: 4px;
        }
        @keyframes pulse {
            0% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(52, 106, 180, 1);} 
            100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 106, 180, 0.0);}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that you tried? It looks like you are just pasting the original code and not what you have tried.

Comment: Could you share your codepen? You only shared other code that works and your edited code which has the problem. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I didn't really change much, i didn't say it doesn't work, it just isn't responsive. 
I just changed values of some dots from percentages to vw and vh and resized my browser, but they still weren't responsive.

I guess thats enough to say that vw and vh aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work perfectly responsive for me. You can use `vh` but I think you forgot to remove the media `height` and `width` attribute. You dont have to change it in the media query when the `height` and `width` is corresponding to the viewport

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(52, 106, 180, 1);} 
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px rgba(52, 106, 180, 0.0);}
}

body {
    background-color: #111114;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#map {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dot {
    width: 5vh;
    height: 5vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: pulse 1.5s infinite ease-out;
    background: #346ab4;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 1vh;
        height: 1vh;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
    &:nth-child(odd) { 
        animation: pulse 1.5s infinite ease-out 0.3s; 
    }
    &-1 { top: 34%; left: 14.5%; }
    &-2 { top: 43%; left: 15.5%; }
    &-3 { top: 51%; left: 20.5%; }
    &-4 { top: 61%; left: 27%; }
    &-5 { top: 68%; left: 29%; }
    &-6 { top: 79%; left: 29%; }
    &-7 { top: 39%; left: 47%; }
    &-8 { top: 30%; left: 46%; }
    &-9 { top: 27%; left: 47%; }
    &-10 { top: 31%; left: 47.5%; }
    &-11 { top: 34%; left: 48.5%; }
    &-12 { top: 47%; left: 53%; }
    &-13 { top: 56%; left: 47.5%; }
    &-14 { top: 78%; left: 53%; }
    &-15 { top: 56%; left: 76%; }
    &-16 { top: 62%; left: 78%; }
    &-17 { top: 41%; left: 79%; }
    &-18 { top: 52%; left: 70%; }
    &-19 { top: 26%; left: 51.5%; }
    &-20 { top: 39%; left: 27%; }
    &-21 { top: 82%; left: 88.5%; }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        @keyframes pulse {
            0% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(52, 106, 180, 1);} 
            100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(52, 106, 180, 0.0);}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't responsive for me. When i make my browser to width and height of mobile, the dots go below the map..

Comment: Which width and height did you use and in which browser did you try it? It works for me perfectly fine in Chrome, using 411px to 731px

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works. 
I was just too dumb, i was using an svg element, so it resized differently, i don't know why. I downloaded a static image of the map now, and it works perfectly.